# Hibernate - Selectively print queries in the logs

Tags: java, hibernate, logback, slf4j

I saw this [link](http://How%20to%20print%20a%20query%20string%20with%20parameter%20values%20when%20using%20Hibernate) which has the details of printing sql query along with parameters. Is there a way to selectively print the queries using any configuration in logback - say for example I want to just print insert and update statements and not select or print only operations done to certain tables.

Similarly I also see the below being printed. I want the log statement to start from "insert into". Is there a way to exclude any before the actual sql statement without having to build custom appenders?

`batching 1 statements: 0: insert into.....`

Comment: Bad link is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex fitlering

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#matcher

Should be doable to discinct SELECT from INSERT